# How to run command for processing HCRF(Hidden- state Conditional Random Field)?

Tags: machine-learning, crf

Do we have to run the command twice, once for training and then again for testing like given below

```
1. testHCRF -t -d dataTrain.csv -l labelsTrain.csv -o bfgs -a hcrf
2. testHCRF -T -D dataTest.csv -L labelsTest.csv -m model.txt -f features.txt -r results.txt -c stats.txt -o bfgs -a hcrf
```

or all at once, like

```
testHCRF -t -T -d dataTrain.csv -l labelsTrain.csv -D dataTest.csv -L labelsTest.csv -m model.txt -f features.txt -r results.txt -c stats.txt -o bfgs -a hcrf
```

Comment: and did you test it?

Comment: Yes. I got is tested.